# Filtering based on SSRS total/sum

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2012.

I have searched the net and the stackoverflow archives and found a few others who have had this problem but I could not get their solutions to work for me. The problem involves filtering based on the aggregate value of a dataset using a user definable report parameter.

I have the following report.

[image: SSRS1]

The ultimate goal of this report is to filter portfolios that have a user definable % of cash as a percent of total assets. The default will be 30% or greater. So for example if a Portfolios total market value was $100,000 and their cash asset class was $40,000 this would be a cash perent of 40% and this portfolio would appear on the report.

I have been able to select just the cash asset class using a filter on the dataset itself so that is not an issue. I easily added a cash percent parameter to the dataset but soon realized this is filtering on the row detail not the aggregated sum, and sometimes portfolios have multiple cash accounts. I need the sum of all cash accounts so I can truly know if cash is 30% or greater of total market value.

At first I thought the report was working correctly.

[image: SSRS2]

But after cross referencing this against another report I realized this portfolio only has 2.66 % **total Cash** because it has a large negative balance in a second cash account as well. It's the sum of all cash accounts I care about.

[image: SSRS3]

I want to filter portfolios that have >= cash based on the total line not the detail lines. I suspect I may need to alter the dataset using the scalar function SUM() then building a parameter off that, but I have not had success writing a query to do that. I also would be very interested to know if somehow this can be done in the .rdl layer rather than at the sql dataset level. The SQL for this is a little complicated because the program that this is reporting on requries the use of SQL functions, stored procedures, and parameters.

If the solution involves altering the query to include sum() in the dataset itself, I suspect it is line 20 that needs to be summed

```
a.PercentAssets,
```

Here is the data set for the report.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bafdo2i6pfvdkk4/CashPercentDataSet.sql

and here is the .rdl file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/htg09ypyh7f1a98/cashpercent2.rdl

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in SQL personally. You can use a SUM() aggregate to get the value you're after for each account. You won't want to sum the percents though, you'll want to SUM  the values and then create the percent afterwards once you have the totals. A sum of averages isn't the same as an average of sums (except in some circumstances but we can't assume that).

I would do something like this, though you'll probably need to tweak it to get it working correctly for you. (I also may not fully understanding the meaning of all the columns you're using).

```
SELECT PortfolioBaseCode,totalValue,cashValue,
    (CAST(cashValue AS FLOAT)/totalValue) * 100 AS pcntCash
FROM (
    SELECT b.PortfolioBaseCode,
        SUM(a.MarketValue) AS totalValue
        SUM(CASE s.SecuritySymbol WHEN 'CASH' THEN a.MarketValue ELSE 0 END) AS cashValue
    FROM APXUser.fAppraisal (@ReportData) a 
    LEFT JOIN APXUser.vPortfolioBaseSettingEx b ON b.PortfolioBaseID = a.PortfolioBaseID 
    LEFT JOIN APXUser.vSecurityVariant s ON s.SecurityID = a.SecurityID 
        AND s.SecTypeCode = a.SecTypeCode 
        AND s.IsShort = a.IsShortPosition 
        AND a.PercentAssets >= @PercentAssets
    GROUP BY b.PortfolioBaseCode
) AS t
WHERE (CAST(cashValue AS FLOAT)/totalValue)>=@pcntParameter
```

Alternatively you can use the HAVING clause to filter aggregate functions like a WHERE clause would (though I find this a little less readable):

```
SELECT b.PortfolioBaseCode,
    SUM(a.MarketValue) AS totalValue
    SUM(CASE s.SecuritySymbol WHEN 'CASH'  THEN a.MarketValue ELSE 0 END) AS cashValue,
    (SUM(a.MarketValue)/SUM(CASE s.SecuritySymbol WHEN 'CASH'  THEN a.MarketValue ELSE 0 END))*100 AS cashPcnt
FROM APXUser.fAppraisal (@ReportData) a 
LEFT JOIN APXUser.vPortfolioBaseSettingEx b ON b.PortfolioBaseID = a.PortfolioBaseID 
LEFT JOIN APXUser.vSecurityVariant s ON s.SecurityID = a.SecurityID 
    AND s.SecTypeCode = a.SecTypeCode 
    AND s.IsShort = a.IsShortPosition 
    AND a.PercentAssets >= @PercentAssets
GROUP BY b.PortfolioBaseCode
HAVING (SUM(a.MarketValue)/SUM(CASE s.SecuritySymbol WHEN 'CASH'  THEN a.MarketValue ELSE 0 END))>=@pcntParameter
```

Basically you can use grouping and aggregate functions to get the total value and the cash value for each account and then calculate the proper percentage from that. This will take into account any negatives, etc in other holdings.

Some references for aggregate function and grouping:

[MSDN - GROUP BY (TSQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

[MSDN - Aggregate Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

[MSDN - HAVING Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)

If you find you're needing to do some kind of aggregation but you cannot group your results you should look into using the TSQL window functions which are very handy:

[Working with Window Functions in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/working-with-window-functions-in-sql-server/)

[MSDN - OVER Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It's not quite working. I've tried altering your query a little but not quite there yet. One line I changed was  SUM(CASE WHEN s.SecTypeCode ='caus'  THEN a.MarketValue ELSE 0 END) AS cashValue, to filter cash I need it to be s.SecTypeCode ='caus after changing that line I get the error  Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 26
Must declare the scalar variable "@PercentAssets".

Comment: I was testing the query in SSMS even though I want to use it in SSRS I get errors in SSRS too but I find SSMS is good for testing.

Comment: You could always calculate the totalValue and cashValue in SQL and calculate the percentage in the report layer and filter on that. A calculated field would work well for that. I think your paste didn't come through though, so I can't see what you've changed.

Comment: Reality PercentAssets is built into the Appraisal function APXUser.fAppraisal (@ReportData) a but I could manually calculate it if that helps me sum the total line.

Comment: That error is related to you using a variable in your query that hasn't been declared yet. It is from the LEFT JOIN to `APXUser.vSecurityVariant` which I just copied from your query. I think you could probably just remove that line and it will work fine. (You'll probably want to remove the variable I used in my queries as well. I was trying to simulate how you would check it against the parameter value. But if you do that filtering in the report layer it is unecessary.)

Comment: Since I don't know all of the details of your stored procedure or database schema I'm not going to be able to create a complete answer for you. However, you should be able to use grouping and aggregation to come up with the percentage assets without using a stored procedure. Unless of course that stored procedure uses more complicated business logic than a simple summation of the values and division by the total.

Comment: Unfortunately the Stored Procedures as more complicated than just summation. They do indeed use complex business logic. I think some type of SQL aggregation is needed but I'm not able to write the query to accomplish this yet.

Comment: I got a little further using the Partition over funcionality but still can't find a way to filter on just the sum of the calculated Percent of Assets or make that sum a column to be filtered on.

I added the following to the dataset

a.MarketValue/SUM(a.MarketValue)
OVER(Partition by b.PortfolioBaseCode) as MKVPCT,

But this merely recalculates the Percent of Assets I already have of which the sum can't be filtered on.

Comment: In order to filter on the values of an aggregate function you need to use the HAVING clause. Either that or rework the query so that the main query is a table expression that you then filter using the outer query.