# Sum a column pulled from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012

I have a query that pulls derived and dynamic data from a stored procedure then joins various views to it. The query is here.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/cashpercent.sql

I added the following line to my query expecting this to pull the summed result of one of my columns, `PercentAssets`.

Line 21 of query

```
SUM(a.PercentAssets) AS SummedPCT
```

However `SummedPCT` pulls the exact same result as the non summed column `PercentAssets`.

[image: Query1]

What I want is `SummedPCT` to return results shown here in `DesiredResult`

[image: Query2]

The end result of all this is to use this query in a dataset and to filter on the summed column.

I tried to accomplish this through the rdl layer or a different type of query a few days ago when I asked the following question.

[Filtering based on SSRS total/sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173000/filtering-based-on-ssrs-total-sum)

I'm now thinking I just need to accomplish this somehow in the SQL Query itself and create a field that is the summed result of `PercentAssets` than I can filter based on it.

Thank you,

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: added note MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact you are still grouping by the field a.PercentAssets. You cant have an aggregate over a column you have grouped by. To find the SUM of that field you will need to use a [sub query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Any idea how I might write the sub query in this example?

Comment: After experimenting with this I finally got it working. Marked your answer as Correct Rich